# SQL Server 2019. Cannot create index in view because column is "Imprecise,computed and not persisted"

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, view

I want to create an index on a SQL Server view. The column I want to index is defined like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (CAST([LOCAL_DATE] AS float) - FLOOR(CAST([LOCAL_DATE] AS float))) 
         BETWEEN CAST([START_DATE] AS float) - floor(CAST([START_DATE] AS float)))  
             AND (CAST([END_DATE] AS float) - FLOOR(CAST([END_DATE] AS float)))  
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
END AS InTime
```

`LOCAL_DATE` is a `datetime` column in my source table. The `InTime` column in my view is just a flag, so normally it would be a bit, but SQL Server creates it as an `Int` column.

The thing is when I try to create a index in my view, it throws an error stating that the column is is "imprecise, computed and not persisted".

```
CREATE INDEX Index_Name ON [dbo].[MyView](InTime)
```

Is there any workaround for this? I use float conversion to compare datetime, as to my understanding it's the fastest way.

For example DateTime is 1 Jan 2022 12:00

I need to know if this event occurred between 8:00 and 16:00 or not, and show my `InTime` column. So I use

```
(CAST([LOCAL_DATE] AS float) - FLOOR(CAST([LOCAL_DATE] AS float)))
```

to get just the time.

The goal is to speed up any query that request events that occurred `InTime`

---- EDIT/UPDATE -----

After your suggestions, I'm trying with CAST function. But now I get a different error, saying that the column 'InTime' is "non-deterministic"

This is my actual view definition:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[MyView]
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
SELECT        TOP (100) A.LOCAL_DATE,
                             CASE WHEN CAST(LOCAL_DATE AS TIME) BETWEEN (CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, A.LOCAL_DATE) WHEN 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        (CAST(StartDate AS TIME))
                               FROM            [dbo].[SCHEDULLE_TABLE] E
                               WHERE        E.IdCen = A.IdCen) ELSE
                             (SELECT        (CAST(StartDateB AS TIME))
                               FROM            [dbo].[SCHEDULLE_TABLE] E
                               WHERE        E.IdCen = A.IdCen) END) AND (CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, A.LOCAL_DATE) WHEN 1 THEN
                             (SELECT        (CAST(EndDate AS TIME))
                               FROM            [dbo].[SCHEDULLE_TABLE] E
                               WHERE        E.IdCen = A.IdCen)  ELSE
                             (SELECT        (CAST(EndDateB AS TIME))
                               FROM            [dbo].[SCHEDULLE_TABLE] E
                               WHERE        E.IdCen = A.IdCen) END) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS InTime
FROM            dbo.EventTable AS A 
GO
```

Comment: I suggest you simply avoid the float ugliness. IMHO, performance difference compared to native datetime/datetime2 will be imperceptible on modern systems. If you don't believe me, [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: How do you compare only the time part of two datetime fields?. The alternatives I've seen are conversions to varchar, which Will be much slower. Datetimes are actually stored as floats, so dunno if there is any other aceptable way.

Comment: `convert(time, [LOCAL_DATE])` gets the time without date. See example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e3a779915be2b6caa3bc8c321b077e1a

Comment: In addition to the option of just converting straight to a `time`, do you really care about `insert` performance? After all, an indexed view (or indexed computed column, or even just an index in general) speeds up read and does so at the cost of write. At the time of reading the value has already been calculated (during the write). If you need to absolutely maximize both write speed and read speed, then an indexed view is a bit of a non starter, you'd be looking at ODS/data warehouse style solutions.

Comment: "Datetimes are actually stored as floats". Not really. The internal datetime structure is 2 32-bit integers, the first representing the number of days since the 1900-01-01 epoch and the second with the number of 1/300 second units since midnight. You can see this with `CAST(LOCAL_TIME AS binary(8))`. If performance is important to you, consider `datetime2(n)` with the desired precision and use native datetime functions. This will store values more precisely, perform better, and with less storage (`datetime(3)` uses 7 bytes instead of 8.

Comment: @allmhuran I was actually worried about insert performance. Thanks for the confirmation; this is the first time I'm considering indexed views, so didn't know exactly when the index is calculated. I was hoping it happens after the insert is commited, instead of before de commit, so it doesn't impact insert performance. Normally I would do some kind of ETL process periodically, but this customer is demanding real time data, and I want to test this option before completely discarding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast to TIME instead of FLOAT, eg

```
drop table if exists t
create table t
(
    id int identity primary key,
    local_date datetime, 
    start_date datetime, 
    end_date datetime
)
go
create or alter view vt 
with schemabinding
as
    select t.id, t.local_date, t.start_date, t.end_date,
            CASE WHEN CAST([LOCAL_DATE] AS time)
                BETWEEN CAST([START_DATE] AS time) 
                AND CAST([END_DATE] AS time) 
                THEN 1  ELSE 0 END as InTime
    from dbo.t

go
create unique clustered index ix_vt on vt(InTime,id)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I've updated my post, with my actual view definition. With CAST I'm getting non-deterministic error. I have one more table involved in my view's CASE statement, not sure if this might be the reason

Comment: @JackCasas, subqueries are not allowed in indexed views. This makes the view non-deterministic. See [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver16) for specifics on restrictions.

Comment: guess I'm stuck with postprocessing after data is inserted. I will have to do a script to periodically calculate my view or put some code in the insert trigger.. Thanks guys!